# how to pass array data to the javascript code from asp.net page?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, arrays

i have a **chart template** with **javascript code** and this is the part of it:

```
// Toggling Series 
    var datasets = {
        "Iran": {
            label: "IR",
            data: [
                [1988, 483994],
                [1989, 479060],
                [1990, 457648],
                [1991, 401949],
                [1992, 424705],
                [1993, 402375],
                [1994, 377867],
                [1995, 357382],
                [1996, 337946],
                [1997, 336185],
                [1998, 328611],
                [1999, 329421],
                [2000, 342172],
                [2001, 344932],
                [2002, 387303],
                [2003, 440813],
                [2004, 480451],
                [2005, 504638],
                [2006, 528692]
            ]
        },
        "russia": {
            label: "Russia",
            data: [
                [1988, 218000],
                [1989, 203000],
                [1990, 171000],
                [1992, 42500],
                [1993, 37600],
                [1994, 36600],
                [1995, 21700],
                [1996, 19200],
                [1997, 21300],
                [1998, 13600],
                [1999, 14000],
                [2000, 19100],
                [2001, 21300],
                [2002, 23600],
                [2003, 25100],
                [2004, 26100],
                [2005, 31100],
                [2006, 34700]
            ]
        }
   };
```

now i want **pass data from array variable to java script for replace with this data on asp.net page load event.**
how to pass array list to this ? can write a sample code ?

**Note:** my data is big and this java script data is sample only and is better to pass array or variable!

Comment: use web method : http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: @Zaki how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly pass a variable from your .NET application to the client-side JavaScript.  Instead you need to either include the full list data in the script source (as you've done partially above) or use AJAX or similar to query the data from the server.

You can shorten the code using something like JSON.net to serialize the object you're trying to embed:

```
var datasets = <%= NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.datasets) %>;
```

Or you can write the code to generate the layout yourself... personally I prefer the simpler `JsonConvert` option.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, *(I haven't tested it)*

Create a method in you .cs file :

```
[WebMethod]
  public static string GetData()
  {
    var datasets = {
        "Iran": {
            label: "IR",
            data: [
                [1988, 483994],
                [1989, 479060],
                [1990, 457648],
                [1991, 401949],
                [1992, 424705],
                [1993, 402375],
                [1994, 377867],
                [1995, 357382],
                [1996, 337946],
                [1997, 336185],
                [1998, 328611],
                [1999, 329421],
                [2000, 342172],
                [2001, 344932],
                [2002, 387303],
                [2003, 440813],
                [2004, 480451],
                [2005, 504638],
                [2006, 528692]
            ]
        },
        "russia": {
            label: "Russia",
            data: [
                [1988, 218000],
                [1989, 203000],
                [1990, 171000],
                [1992, 42500],
                [1993, 37600],
                [1994, 36600],
                [1995, 21700],
                [1996, 19200],
                [1997, 21300],
                [1998, 13600],
                [1999, 14000],
                [2000, 19100],
                [2001, 21300],
                [2002, 23600],
                [2003, 25100],
                [2004, 26100],
                [2005, 31100],
                [2006, 34700]
            ]
        }
   };

return dataset;
  }
```

Then in you jquery load/document ready function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/GetData",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $("domelement").html(data);
  }
});
```